# To find the sum of elements of a nested array using a for loop with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a nested loop:

```
const arrays = [
  [4, 32, 8],
  [64, 8, 32],
  [8, 32, 16],
  [2, 8, 4]
]
```

and i want to find the sum of all its elements using a For loop and display the result in the console. How should I do it?

Comment: You should research. There are ample Q&A on the subject.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. *(Note my downvote.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
const arrays = [
  [4, 32, 8],
  [64, 8, 32],
  [8, 32, 16],
  [2, 8, 4]
] 

let sum = 0;
for(let i=0;i<arrays.length;i++){
  for(let j=0;j<arrays[i].length;j++){
    sum +=arrays[i][j];
  }
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6938969/imran-rafiq-rather I did not get any answer, inside the nested array , I have 4 arrays instead of 2.

Comment: @sabine NP, I'll help you God willing. Is the above code not working fine? You require sum of all the elements right?

Comment: @sabine Don't worry brother. Tell me what exactly you require. I'll try to help you. And keep smiling

Comment: Yes, I would like to get the sum of all the items of the nested array https://stackoverflow.com/users/6938969/imran-rafiq-rather?

Comment: @sabine Hello Friend. You mean for nested arrays each sum ????

Comment: I earlier felt you need sum of all the elements together. That's what I have written the code for. What specifically you are looking for. May be I can help you better :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6938969/imran-rafiq-rather yes @Imran , I need to get the sum of all the sub-arrays' elements together.

Comment: Then, You already have my code. You wanted it in `for loop` and I quickly did it in for loop for you. You can test it also, It is working fine.

Comment: Thank you very much https://stackoverflow.com/users/6938969/imran-rafiq-rather .that is the answer. But there is something I do not understand tough Why did I not get the answer( In fact i did not get nothing in the console , it kept looping for ever) while my answer was pretty much like yours.                                                               
let sumOfArrays = 0
for (let i=0;i<arrays.length;i++){
  for(let j=0;j<arrays.length;j++){
    sumOfArrays +=arrays[i][j]
  }
}
console.log(sumOfArrays)  // I got NaN in the console.

Comment: You are most Welcome @sabine 
I am at work right now. I will check your code in the evening and check whether something is wrong. :)

Comment: In your inner `for` loop you had used `for(let j=0;j<arrays.length;j++)` while you should actually use `for(let j=0;j<arrays[i].length;j++)`, So, each sub-Array's length we have to consider.  
`arrays[i]` was missing :) Hope this helps to understand where the issue really was.

God Bless You. If you find any issues related to JS, React, Responsive Web Design, feel free to ask. Though I has 5 days work like other coders, I would try to get some time helping you out InshaAllah. Bye Mate :)

Comment: Okay!!! I have understood my mistake!! Thank you very much https://stackoverflow.com/users/6938969/imran-rafiq-rather